# Mysql broken packages

Tags: package-management, mysql

I am not able to fix broken packages to my ubuntu machine.
I followed many command posted on forums.
Nothing happened!

The packages that have the problem are:

```
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
```

Any way to resolve it? The configuration of my PC is in Greek language and I can't give you some useful output since this problem prevents me from changing the language of console!
Thank you!

Ok, here is the output!

```
 unknown@unknown-pc:~$  sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 
 [sudo] password for unknown: 
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Suggested packages:
 tinyca mailx
 The following packages will be upgraded:
 mysql-server-5.5
 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
 2 not fully installed or removed.
 Need to get 0 B/8746 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
 Preconfiguring packages ...
 (Reading database ... 366372 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to replace mysql-server-5.5 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../mysqlserver-5.5_5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_i386.deb) ...
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mysql not found.
 dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
 dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mysql not found.
 dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mysql not found.
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mysql not found.
 dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_i386.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

unknown@unknown-pc:~$

Comment: you can re-install mysql-server, maybe, problem will be resolved.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Could you please add the error message to your question? You can change the output of Terminal to English by running this command (without quotes): "LC_ALL=C bash".

Comment: You can reinstall a package by running sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client

Comment: I empathize with your exclamation marks man. I've been SO frustrated by this twisted evil set of packages that I'm just reinstalling Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow your package system got screwed. Apparently the file `/etc/init.d/mysql` has been lost in the progress. Add a dummy in order to aid the package system over the loss:

```
$ sudo -i
# cat > /etc/init.d/mysql << EOF
> #!/bin/true
> EOF
# chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mysql
```

... and then remove all mysql packages ...

```
# apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server
```

That should also remove the dummy script. If not, delete it manually. After that you should be able to install mysql as normal again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix broken packages by running the command below from Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: This command I tried many times! No result!

Comment: You could also try running sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server

Comment: Did that and dont work! I got many errors, Thank you!